# Moving an element into a new div - doesn't take on its new css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I have an element that has some "pre-existing" behavior attached to it. So, I found that just moving it (as required by some new requirements) retains the existing behaviors = good. But the issue is, when I move the element I need to give it "new styles".

So, if I have something like this:

```
<div id="existingStructure">
    <div id="legacyElement"></div>
</div>
```

Now, that has pre-existing styles attached to both. I can rearrange these styles etc.. but I can't change them. The styles are attached to the "id's" rather than a class definition. I believe I can change that if needed.

Now, I need to move "legacyElement" when certain things happen to a "new div".
I just

```
jQuery('#newStructure').append('#legacyElement');

<div id="newStructure">
    <div id="legacyElement"></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunetly, the styles I have on newStructure don't seem to be applying to *legacyElement" when it gets moved here dynamically.

I was thinking of moving all the styles to a class rather than associated to the ids, and when I move it.. I just jQuery().addClass / jQuery().removeClass etc...

Is there a better/easier more robust way that I can just have the *legacyElement* loose its styles when it sits under *existingStructure* and then get new ones when moved to "newStructure" etc.. and vice versa. That element "legacyElement" will be pinging back and forth.. so, I need it to have the styles under each parent div as it goes there.

so when an action happens on page, I move it back:

```
jQuery('#existingStructure').append('#legacyElement');
```

If I am not succinct enough, please let me know.

The EXISTING styles are in an external CSS file and are like so..

```
#existingStructure {
   // bunch of css
 }

#existingStructure .item1 input[type="text"] {
   // bunch of css
}

 #legacyElement{
   // bunch of css
  }
```

and new styles are sorta the same except 'additional styles' might be applied.

```
#newStructure {
   // bunch of css
 }

#newStructure .item1 input[type="text"] {
   // bunch of css
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the styles?

Comment: The styles are set in a CSS file.. like so: dang. can't do it here, see original post.. edit that.

Comment: You know it's `jQuery('#existingStructure').append($('#legacyElement'));` Notice the extra jQuery search call inside `.append()`.

Comment: yeah, just short-handing it. thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly target your div styles by their parents:

```
#existingStructure #legacyElement {some styles}
#newStructure #legacyElement {some other styles}
```

To explain futher, this arrangement should result in greater specificity, overriding styles that are simply applied to either #existingStructure or #legacyElement. I'm hoping no one did anything foolish like using !important on them.

Comment: hmm. let me try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It should.

Here's an example I quickly made in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CCm4J/1/

So then why isn't yours? Most likely you have css rules that are embedded that apply only when in the `existingStructure` id/class perhaps?  Without see more of your css I'm not sure how specific I can get. I would just verify that your css rules are allowed to apply outside of `existingStructure` (and even that `existingStructure` might have rules for *its* parent too!)